# Can someone please explain the output java

Tags: java, jgrasp

I am having a little trouble understanding the output of the following code. Can someone explain the exact steps so I can better understand what is going on?

```
public class Foo {
    private static int id = 0 ;
    private int myId ;

    public Foo() {
        myId = id ;
        ++id ;
    }

    public int getMyId() {
        return myId ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo f1 = new Foo();
        Foo f2 = new Foo();
        System.out.println(f1.getMyId());
        System.out.println(f2.getMyId());
        System.out.println(id); 
    }
}
```

Can you explain why the output is equal to:

```
 0
 1
 2
```

Comment: Have you tried walking through it yourself? If so, which exact part are you getting confused on?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and fix the indetion of your code? It is very hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create F1, myId = 0 because id = 0.
2. In the constructor we increment id by 1.
3. Create F2, myId = 1 because we just incremented id.
4. In the constructor we increment id by 1 again.
5. Print the value of myId from F1 which is still 0.
6. Print the value of myId from F2 which is still 1.
7. Print the value of id which is static and therefore shared between instances.. it is 2 after the last increment.

I assume you find the static part confusing, this variable is effectively kept once in this case. With 10 Foo instances there will still only be 1 "static" id (which is incremented each time you create a new instance of Foo).

Answer (score 0):

the Class Foo has a static field that called id `private static int id` that will get incremented each time an instance of that class calls `public int getMyId(){....}` this example where ever you have seen it wants to make the distinction between object('instance') and class so when you have 2 objects foo1 and foo2 and they both call the public method `getMyId` the static variable get incremented independently of what object is calling it foo1 or foo2 and the id variable is visible to both of those object foo1 and foo2 in the other hand id is a field that is not static so it is the "property" of object so id of object foo1 is not visible to object foo2 and vice versa .

So when the class is first created the static field 'id' get value 0

then the call foo1.getMyId make field myId have the value stored in id which is 0 then increment id so id now has value 1

the call foo2.getMyId() will put the value in id wich is 1 in myId ,increment id now id has value 2 the return value myId

the call id is like call Foo.id so it will give you the id value wich is 2